# nodejs lambda post request timeout

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, httprequest

I am trying to put a post request in my nodejs lambda function to another lambda function. It's not giving me any response and is timing out. If I do a post request from postman, the other lambda function is giving me the proper response.

The first lambda function is connected to a VPC. The VPC is also connected to an Internet Gateway, so lambda should have internet access.

here is the post request I have put to my other lambda function.

```
var options = { method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://jsmykktis3.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/production',
  headers: 
   { 'postman-token': 'ea43388d-e2e8-3c1c-60d3-9e3cdfbda5a3',
     'cache-control': 'no-cache' },
  body: '{ "user": \r\n{ "first_name": "naman",\r\n"last_name": "Bansal",\r\n"email": "someemail@gmail.com",\r\n"course": "hello",\r\n"joined": "2018-05-17T20:38:32.000Z" },\r\n"metadata": \r\n{ "from_date": "2018/06/07 07:48:30",\r\n"to_date": "2018/08/06 07:48:30" }\r\n}' };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log("inside the response"); //not getting anything in console
  console.log(body);                  
});
```

I have also tried using 'HTTP' and 'axios' node modules to put post request, I am getting the same results.

Comment: hrmm, is that your full code?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no specific reason to call another lambda through network, `invoke` is recommended. Maybe the problem will be solved.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property